# How do I prevent apt/apt-get from cancellng download of multiple packages if one of them can't be found

Tags: list, installation, apt, apt-get

I am trying to write a package install script for Ubntu which is based on apt-get with a list of packages as parameter (like `xargs -a ./packages_list.txt sudo apt-get -y -f -m install` or `sudo apt-get -y -f -m install  $(cat packages_list.txt)`).

It might happen that one of the packages in the list in `packages_list.txt` can't be found by apt. In this case that package should be ignored but all other should be installed.

So what I expect e.g. from the command `sudo apt-get -y -f -m install curl wget apt-transport-https xargs dos2unix vim` is that if *xargs* can't be found/downloaded by *apt, curl, wget, apt-transport-https, dos2unix* and *vim* still get installed.

But what actually is happening that I get the message (in German) `E: xargs kann nicht gefunden werden.` ("*E: xargs can't be found.*") and the rest of the list, e.g. *apt-transport-https*, does not get installed.

My understanding is, that `-m` (or `--ignore-missing`) should prevent this behavior. But this is not the case.

So how can I achieve that all other packages in apt's parameter list still get installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `while read` loop to install the packages from list on by one:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
while IFS= read -r package; do sudo apt -y install "$package"; done < packages_list.txt
```

If some packages fails to be installed the installation process will continue.

without looping:

```
xargs apt list 2>/dev/null < packages_list.txt | \
awk -F'/' '/\//{print $1}' | xargs sudo apt install -y
```

Comment: This is a working soluton. Thank you! It would be nice, of course, if there was a solution without calling apt in a loop as a workarund.

Comment: @gth3q I have updated my answer, the first command will check and filtre the avilable package , the second one will install them.

Comment: Both solutions are great. Thank you for your help!